# Finding two functions, $f, g$, such that $\mathrm{sup}(g \circ f[\omega]) < \mathrm{sup} (g[\omega + \omega])$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I've been working for some time on Schimmerling's *A course on Set Theory*, and, thanks to you guys, I'm now almost finishing chapter 3 on ordinals (hah!). In one of the last exercises, he ask us to find the two functions $f, g$ which obey the following conditions: $f: \omega \to \omega + \omega$, $g: \omega + \omega \to \omega + \omega + \omega$, $\mathrm{sup}(f[\omega]) = \omega + \omega$, $\mathrm{sup}(g[\omega + \omega]) = \omega + \omega + \omega$ and $\mathrm{sup}(g \circ f[\omega]) < \omega + \omega + \omega$.

I thought a little bit about this but couldn't think of functions other than ordinal addition, which (I think) won't give the desired result. If someone could give me a hint in the right direction, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Take $f$ to be a function whose range does not include any infinite intervals; and then pick $g$ to be constant on the range of $f$ and increasing on its complement.

Comment: When you say that $f$'s range shouldn't include any infinite intervals, you mean that its range shouldn't include infinite chains (i.e. "$x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \dots$")?

Comment: No, I mean to say that $f$ shouldn't be something like $f(n)=\omega+n$, or something similar. In that case the range of $f$ includes the interval $[\omega,\omega+\omega)$. Of course, you can weaken this requirement a bit more. But this way it's relatively easy to understand the idea: have enough room for $g$ to reach $\omega+\omega+\omega$, while staying constant on the range of $f$.

Comment: And I think that if you understand the idea here, then you can find even a myriad of simpler solutions.

Comment: So the range of $f$ must be bounded from above by, say, $\omega + n$, but $\mathrm{sup}(f[\omega])$ must be $\omega + \omega$?

Comment: What? No. Take $f(n)=\omega+2n$ as a canonical example.

Comment: So the idea is that the range of $f$ should be "gappy"?

Comment: Yes, or in other words, that it won't include an infinite interval (in which case, it will not be "gappy").

Comment: Now that you've had some time to think, consider any function $f$ whose range is co-infinite, and $g$ which is $0$ on the range of $f$, but has a cofinal increasing sequence on its complement. For example, $f(n)=\omega+n$ and $g(n)=\omega+\omega+n$ for $n<\omega$, and $g(\alpha)=0$ for $\alpha\geq\omega$. That also works out just fine.

Comment: So part of the trick is defining $g$ separately to cover the cases where $g$ overlaps with the range of $f$, right? This means that $g$ can't be monotonic, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. And you can easily prove that you can't have $g$ monotonic, since then every cofinal subset of the range has a cofinal image in the range, meaning $\sup(g\circ f[\omega])=\omega+\omega+\omega$.